# Does YouTube live streaming support HLS (HTTP Live Streaming)?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, http-live-streaming, youtube-livestreaming-api

I'm a newcomer. I know YouTube live streaming supports RTMP, but I cannot find HLS encoder settings. Does it support HLS? I want to broadcast an HLS streaming via YouTube.

Answer (score 8):

Short answer: Yes

Long answer:

The [official page](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2853702?hl=en&ref_topic=2853712) says:

> Mobile streaming: Live events will be automatically available on
>   iPhone, iPad, iPod Touch & Android 4.0+ mobile devices via
>   m.youtube.com.

This sounds a lot like a HLS fallback.

Using an iPad user-agent and sniffing network traffic I found the following request to a Google server:

**HTTP GET**

```
/api/manifest/hls_variant/sparams/gcr,id,ip,ipbits,itag,playlist_type,pmbypass,source,expire/source/yt_live_broadcast/[redacted]/index.m3u8?[redacted]
```

and response:

**HTTP/1.1 200 OK**
Content-Type: **application/vnd.apple.mpegurl**

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=380059,CODECS="avc1.4d0015,mp4a.40.5",RESOLUTION=426x240,CLOSED-CAPTIONS=NONE
http://manifest.googlevideo.com/api/manifest/hls_playlist/id/ANM-dq5USTc.1/itag/92/source/yt_live_broadcast/ratebypass/yes/live/1/cmbypass/yes/gir/yes/dg_shard[..]
```

So yeah, I guess YouTube live supports HLS.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I guess you misunderstood my question. I mean I want to create a live broadcast streaming, but my stream is HLS. I know Youtube live events can be played in iOS. However, does it support HLS encoding when we create a live streaming?

Comment: For input there's only RTMP so far.

Answer (score 5):

A [`liveStream`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveStreams) object contains a `cdn` object with the [`ingestionType`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveStreams#cdn.ingestionType) property.  This String property is used to declare the method or protocol used to transmit the video stream.

The only supported transmission format at this time is `rtmp`.  HLS is not supported at this time but is on YouTube's roadmap for supported upstream formats.

As of April 2016, YouTube has added DASH as a supported ingestion video format.

Comment: There are two protocols as far as broadcast a live stream: 1) the protocol to upload/publish to Youtube; 2) and the protocol Youtube broadcast to the end user.

Is ingestionType the protocol to upload to Youtube system or the Youtube users to watch (download) the video?

Comment: @chen The upstream, at least as far as I know.  Considering you can play back live events in any webpage/web view, YouTube must support a multitude of downstream formats.

Comment: I was reading a blog about [Facebook Live](https://code.facebook.com/posts/1653074404941839/under-the-hood-broadcasting-live-video-to-millions/), and Facebook Live team seemed to use RTMP as the downstream protocol to bring down the latency, any thoughts?

Comment: Since April we now offer DASH ingestion, which is similar to HLS. https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/guides/encoding-with-dash

Comment: @MarcChambers Hey, thanks!  Glad YouTube hired another dev relations engineer!

Comment: @MarcChambers just discovering this 2016 thread, any chance HLS ingestion is supported now?

Comment: @tamak `rtmp` and `dash` are still the only two ingestion types.  Review the [API docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveStreams#cdn.ingestionType).